# how to use the keyword on in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<li class = "item" data-id="0">Test<p>Test</p></li>
```

li doesn't get added to the page automatically. It gets generated using ajax. How do I stimulate a click event when someone clicks on a li? I understand I have to use the "on" keyword. I tried that but it is not working. How do I use the on key word to change the value of the nearest p in the li?

Here's what I have

```
    $(document).on("click", ".item", function(e){
        var target = e.target;
        console.log(target);
        var id = $(e).dataset.id;
        console.log(id);
        var mark = $(e).closest('p');
        IssueViewer.showItem(id, mark);
    });
```

Comment: `on` is not a [JavaScript keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords), it is a method of the jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

Within the click handler, use `$(this).find('p')` to target the `p` element, and `$(this).data('id')` to get clicked `li`'s data-id:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  var id= $(this).data('id');
  
  $(this).find('p').text('Changed: '+id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item" data-id="0">Test<p>Test</p></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how do I get the data-id tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I have included explanations inside using comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
  $(".item").click(function(){ /* WHEN AN LI WITH A CLASS OF ITEM IS CLICKED */

    var elem = $(this); /* THE CLICKED ELEMENT */
    var etarget = elem.target; /* GET THE HTML ELEMENT */
    console.log(etarget); /* PRINT TO THE CONSOLE THE ELEMENT THAT WAS CLICKED */
    var id = elem.attr("data-id"); /* GET THE ID OF THE CLICKED LI */
    console.log(id); /* PRINT TO THE CONSOLE THE ID OF THE CLICK LI */
    elem.find("p").html(id); /* CHANGE THE CONTENT OF THE P CHILD */

  });
});
```

You can also check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/pr6j43ww/).